# JS - conjoin array of arrays by first item

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays:

```
[
    [
        "DL"
    ],
    [
        "DL",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "MQ"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "DFW"
    ],
    [
        "WN"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "MDW"
    ],
    [
        "EV"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "IAH"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "LAS"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "ORD"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "BWI"
    ]
]
```

They are already sorted by some specific order, but what I want to do is now sort them again and have all items with more than one item in the array moved in the current order below the item with one item in the array.
e.g

```
[
    [
        "DL"
    ],
    [
        "DL",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "MQ"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "DFW"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "ORD"
    ],
    [
        "WN"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "MDW"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "LAS"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "BWI"
    ]
    [
        "EV"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "IAH"
    ],
]
```

note that the last three items moved up:

```
    [
        "WN",
        "LAS"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "ORD"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "BWI"
    ]
```

to be the last items below `MQ` and `WN`.
WITHOUT losing the order.

meaning:

- `MQ/ORD` was moved just below `MQ/DFW`.
- `WN/LAS` and `WN/BWI` were moved just below `WN/MDW` without losing the order.

Any suggestion for a simple and elegant way to do that?

**BONUS:**

If possible, the suggested algorithm should handle also the reverse logic:

e.g

```
[
    [
        "WN",
        "BWI"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "ORD"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "LAS"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "IAH"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "MDW"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "DFW"
    ],
    [
        "US"
    ],
    [
        "US",
        "CLT"
    ],
    [
        "EV"
    ],
    [
        "MQ"
    ],
    [
        "AA"
    ],
    [
        "AA",
        "DFW"
    ],
    [
        "DL"
    ],
    [
        "DL",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "WN"
    ]
]
```

Where again, it should be nested in the same way, without losing the order of the "TOP" items (US should be above EV) and all the items nested below in the same order:

```
[
    [
        "US"
    ],
    [
        "US",
        "CLT"
    ],
    [
        "EV"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "IAH"
    ],
    [
        "EV",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "MQ"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "ORD"
    ],
    [
        "MQ",
        "DFW"
    ],
    [
        "AA"
    ],
    [
        "AA",
        "DFW"
    ],
    [
        "DL"
    ],
    [
        "DL",
        "ATL"
    ],
    [
        "WN"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "BWI"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "LAS"
    ],
    [
        "WN",
        "MDW"
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First map into parent-child relationships then transform it into a resulting array:

```js
// swapped the first 2 elements to handle a case of a child going before its parent

const arr = [["DL","ATL"], ["DL"],["MQ"],["MQ","DFW"],["WN"],["WN","MDW"],["EV"],["EV","ATL"],["EV","IAH"],["WN","LAS"],["MQ","ORD"],["WN","BWI"]];

const mapped = 
  arr.reduce((map, item) => {
    map[item[0]] ??= [];
    item.length > 1 && map[item[0]].push(item);
    return map;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(mapped).reduce((result, [key, val]) => {
  result.push([key], ...val);
  return result; 
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

A more elegant solution would be using `sort()`, but it's much slower .

```js
const arr = [["DL", "ATL"], ["DL"], ["MQ"], ["MQ", "DFW"], ["WN"], ["WN", "MDW"], ["EV"], ["EV", "ATL"], ["EV", "IAH"], ["WN", "LAS"], ["MQ", "ORD"], ["WN", "BWI"]];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    
    // if items on the same level or have a different parent
    if (a.length === b.length || a[0] !== b[0]) {
        // sort by parent index
        return arr.findIndex(item => item[0] === a[0]) - 
          arr.findIndex(item => item[0] === b[0]);
    }

    return a.length - b.length;

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

And benchmarking the two with the array increased 500x in size:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const original = [["DL", "ATL"], ["DL"], ["MQ"], ["MQ", "DFW"], ["WN"], ["WN", "MDW"], ["EV"], ["EV", "ATL"], ["EV", "IAH"], ["WN", "LAS"], ["MQ", "ORD"], ["WN", "BWI"]];

    // increase the input array 500x
    const getData = () => Array.from({ length: 500 }, (_, idx) => original.map(item => {
        return item.map(name => `${name}${idx}`);
    }))
        .flat();

    // @benchmark mapped solution

    const arr = getData();

    // @run

    const mapped =
        arr.reduce((map, item) => {
            map[item[0]] ??= [];
            item.length > 1 && map[item[0]].push(item);
            return map;
        }, {});

    Object.entries(mapped).reduce((result, [key, val]) => {
        result.push([key], ...val);
        return result;
    }, []);


    // @benchmark sort solution

    const arr2 = getData();

    // @run

    arr2.sort((a, b) => {

        if (a.length === b.length || a[0] !== b[0]) {
            return arr2.findIndex(item => item[0] === a[0]) -
                arr2.findIndex(item => item[0] === b[0]);
        }

        return a.length - b.length;

    });

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not the solution I was asked for :) – 
It's sorting ALL the items in alphabetical order, but I need to preserve the order and only nest the items by first element as in my example

Comment: `EV` elements should stay last

Comment: I wish it could be simpler solution - but this is awesome! working!

Comment: @ET-CS i'm trying to make it with `sort()`. i'll notify if i come to a solution.

Comment: Few bad practices in this code. which es-lint doesn't like. such as param reassign inside the reduce, or for..in instead of Object.values()... nothing I can't fix :)

Comment: @ET-CS i see no param reassigning, i wish i would have your .eslintrc.js, fixing)

Comment: @ET-CS could you give me the eslint's param reassinging rule?

Comment: That's ok. I will handle the estlint issues :)

Comment: Note: This code is assumes that the one-elements arrays will be always first. I have updated the question with bonus part of reverse order. which is viable condition I have in my app. If anyone have nice solution that handle both it will be great :)

Comment: @ET-CS check it, made a specific case when a child goes before its parent

Comment: no-param-reassign   -    no-unused-expressions    -   no-restricted-syntax

Comment: note that I added a bonus part, for the reverse logic. any idea how to support both ways in your logic?

Comment: @ET-CS i've already implemented the bonus part, check it pls

Comment: One thing :) you have a bug in your code. Look at your console.. it has objects instead of arrays for the single items (`DL` instead of `['DL']`)

Comment: @ET-CS yes, fixing, also i have a sort() solution!

Comment: `arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).filter(a => a.length === 1).flatMap(a => arr.filter(b => b[0] === a[0]))`

Comment: @Thomas doesn't handle a child going before its parent

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev yes it does, that's what the `sort()` is for.

Comment: Amazing! So I see that the sort is less efficient than map!

Comment: @Thomas oops, i was wrong, it doesn't work at all: [["DL"],["MQ"],["WN"],["EV"],["DL","ATL"],["MQ","DFW"],["WN","MDW"],["EV","ATL"],["EV","IAH"],["WN","LAS"],["MQ","ORD"],["WN","BWI"]]

Comment: @ET-CS updated the benchmark and seems the sort is MUCH slower...